# ubuntu boot problems

Tags: boot, wubi

I installed ubuntu 11.10 using wubi on an old HP Compaq nx7400 laptop. It has worked fine until recently, but now whenever I try to boot it freezes. I first get the usual boot screen, with the colored progress dots, but then it switches to a textual mode and stops... the curser just blinks and blinks, nothing ever happens. I am wondering what the problem is and how I can fix it.

Note: I recently tried upgrading to 12.04 beta, but there was not enough space left on my hard drive.

Comment: Mhh do you have any possibility here, of it just freezes and nothing can be done? No messages, no nothing?

Comment: Actually, do you get a GRUB screen right? Do you have entries in there?

Comment: I get a GRUB screen, select Ubuntu 11.10, try and boot, but right before LightDM should appear the screen goes black and it looks like it will go to a textual login, but the curser just blinks and I can't log in. It seems to be responding as when I press Power it tells everything to shut down.

Answer (score 1):

when you boot up in grub, you should see a little list saying Ubuntu 11.10 and just below it you get something like: Ubuntu Recovery Mode or something like it, I don't remember exactly right now, but you should try it :)

Comment: I am in recovery mode right now... did so to post this.

Comment: if it's not a problem, i would erase and install again. if that's an issue, i'd try to install xubuntu and see if with xfce i can get to a workable environment, then get some more time to debug.. you can install xubuntu and ubuntu together